# Ordering data when using Statsmodel Autocorrelation Function

Tags: python, statsmodels, autocorrelation

When using Statsmodel ACF (and PACF) function, the input is an 1-d array, hence no timestamp passed to the function. Should the data passed in that array be chronologically ordered (first element of the array is the datapoint related to the oldest date) or reversed (first element is the latest observation of the data)?

Apologies if this is a stupid quesiton, but I can't seem to find this clearly stated in the [docs](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.acf.html#statsmodels.tsa.stattools.acf)

Thank you,

Comment: In general, time series for statsmodels.tsa and other packages assume what you call chronologically ordered.

Comment: Thank you Josef, is there a source to back this up, i couldn't find anything in the docs (which is not to say that it is not there). Testing for a timeseries both in chronological order and reversed shows exactly the same results.

Comment: The chronological order is an implicit requirement, e.g. forecasting is always at the end. Some operations, like acf, can be symmetric forwards and backwards in time, and in those cases it is irrelevant. For example, correlation between x and y is the same as the correlation between y and x.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the order is irrelevant to the computation of AFC, as long as the order of elements is respected.